# GridBagLayout showing these components apart from each other

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

[i want it to be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIx6A.png)I am practicing `[GridBagLayout]` and I have search it on net but I don't find the answer of my problem then I come here so to find some help , why they are going apart from each other

```
package swing;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class StudentProfile extends JFrame {

    public StudentProfile() {
        super("Student Profile");
        setSize(400, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        Container c = getContentPane();

        c.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 5;
        gbc.anchor =  GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        JLabel stProfile = new JLabel("Student Profile");
        c.add(stProfile, gbc);

        JPanel j1 = new JPanel();
        j1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc1.gridx = 0;
        gbc1.gridy = 0;
        JLabel stName = new JLabel("Student Name", SwingConstants.LEFT);
        j1.add(stName, gbc1);

        gbc1.gridy = 1;
        JLabel fName = new JLabel("Father Name", SwingConstants.LEFT);
        j1.add(fName, gbc1);

        gbc.gridy = 1;
        c.add(j1, gbc);
    }

    public static void main (String[] agrs) {
        StudentProfile sp = new StudentProfile();
        sp.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCq42.png)

Comment: Please read [mcve] and update your question. Clearly describe expected and actual behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is in weights. Make `weighty=1` right before you place your last element. And use `Insets` to create gaps between components. See comments in code below. Remember to use `gbc.fill`, which makes components stretch in direction you specify (`HORIZONTAL`, `VERTICAL`, `BOTH`, `NONE`). Also, you are messing a lot with your `gbc` and `gbc1` objects. Try refactoring your code into smaller classes/methods - read [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Generally, using numbers in variable's names is not a good idea.

SSCCE

```
public class StudentProfile extends JFrame {

    public StudentProfile() {
    super("Student Profile");
    setSize(400, 400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    Container c = getContentPane();

    c.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 10, 0); //<---1 this to make a bottom gap after first label
    gbc.weightx = 1.0;
    //gbc.weighty = 1.0; <---2 take this from here
    gbc.gridheight = 1;
    gbc.gridwidth = 5;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    JLabel stProfile = new JLabel("Student Profile");
    c.add(stProfile, gbc);

    gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0); //<---1 reset insets

    JPanel j1 = new JPanel();
    j1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc1 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc1.gridx = 0;
    gbc1.gridy = 0;
    JLabel stName = new JLabel("Student Name", SwingConstants.LEFT);
    j1.add(stName, gbc1);

    gbc1.gridy = 1;
    JLabel fName = new JLabel("Father Name", SwingConstants.LEFT);
    j1.add(fName, gbc1);
    gbc.weighty = 1.0; //<---2 here
    gbc.gridy = 1;

    c.add(j1, gbc);
}

public static void main (String[] agrs) {
    StudentProfile sp = new StudentProfile();
    sp.setVisible(true);
}
```

Result:

[image: Result layout]

Also, take a look at this code, which is a modified version of yours.

```
public class StudentProfile extends JFrame {

    private Container container;
    private JPanel studentProfileInfoPanel;

    public StudentProfile(String title) {
        super(title);
    }

    public void createStudentProfile() {
        this.setSize(400, 400);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        this.container = this.getContentPane();

        this.container.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 10, 0);
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.gridx=0;
        gbc.gridy=0;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;

        JLabel studentProfileLabel = new JLabel("Student Profile");
        this.container.add(studentProfileLabel, gbc);

        this.createStudentProfileInfoPanel();

        gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        //gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.NONE; //<--- try using this, see what happens
        this.container.add(studentProfileInfoPanel, gbc);
    }

    private void createStudentProfileInfoPanel() {
        this.studentProfileInfoPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,10);
        gbc.weightx = 1;

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        JLabel studentNameLabel = new JLabel("Student Name");
        this.studentProfileInfoPanel.add(studentNameLabel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        this.studentProfileInfoPanel.add(new JLabel ("Adam Smith Jr"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx=0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        JLabel studentFatherNameLabel = new JLabel("Father Name");
        this.studentProfileInfoPanel.add(studentFatherNameLabel, gbc);

        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.gridx++;
        this.studentProfileInfoPanel.add(new JLabel("Adam Smith"), gbc);
    }

    public static void main(String[] agrs) {
        StudentProfile studentProfile = new StudentProfile("Student Profile");
        studentProfile.createStudentProfile();

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            studentProfile.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

If this helps, accept this answer. :)

Comment: actually i accepted your previous code i try to accept it when you give me solution but due to some reason i unable to accept your solution thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to try with ***.insets*** to set top,bottom,left and right margin.
Beware that you need to initialize *new Insets()* object that will take arguments of foretold margins.

*EDIT:*

I browsed through the code once again and actually, you do not have to use insets for what you want to achieve.

```
public class Fixed_StudentProfile extends JFrame {

private JLabel stProfile_label;
private JLabel stName_label;
private JLabel fatherName_label;

public Fixed_StudentProfile() {
    super("Student profile");

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(400, 400);
    setVisible(true);
    createView();

}

public void createView() {

    stProfile_label = new JLabel("Student profile: ");
    stName_label = new JLabel("Name: ");
    fatherName_label = new JLabel("Father: ");

    JPanel panelMain = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(panelMain,BorderLayout.WEST);

    JPanel panelForm = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    panelMain.add(panelForm, BorderLayout.WEST);

    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0; 
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;

    panelForm.add(stProfile_label, c);
    c.gridy++; // move down the line
    panelForm.add(stName_label, c);
    c.gridy++; // move down the line
    panelForm.add(fatherName_label, c);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Fixed_StudentProfile s = new Fixed_StudentProfile();
}
```

***1.*** It is a good practice to **declare your components as global variables** rather than local ones.

***2.*** **Create JPanel**, add it to the ContentPane and **set the BorderLayout to WEST!**
(You are going to add your components(labels) to JPanel and not JFrame).

***3.*** Everything else is rather simple, **create GridBagConstraints object**.

***4.*** Beware of **setting an ANCHOR to FIRST_LINE_START**.

***5.*** This is basically it, now you just have to **increment your gridy axis** as you want your components to be aligned that way.

---

In addition to the insets I mentioned above you can try to add this
   line of code after you created GridBagConstraints object.

```
c.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
```

This will add nice spacing around the area of your JLabel and you will effectively avoid it look so dense.

Comment: This does not completely answer the question. Put it in his example